# Can git work via ssh port forwarding?

Tags: git, ssh

My situation is, I can ssh to ComputerB (Code repos) where git repos is put. But my local
connection is too slow to clone the code. And I can ssh to another machine (ComputerA)
which is faster, so I want to clone the code through ComputerA.

This is what I did:

```
           ssh tunnel                           ssh tunnel
MyComputer ----------> ComputerA (I can ssh to) ----------> ComputerB (where the Code repos is and I can ssh to but too slow)
```

Using a command like this:

```
ssh -L1234:ComputerA_ip:22 Code_repos_ip
```

Then:

```
git clone git+ssh//localhost/repos local_repos (how can I assign the port 1234?)
```

If this doesn't work, what else can I do?

Comment: I wrote a complete response/guide here: http://vladzloteanu.wordpress.com/2010/12/18/git-through-ssh-port-forwarding-ssh-tunneling/.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How will going through two connections make your connection faster?

Anyhow, you should be able to do:

```
git clone git+ssh://localhost:1234/repos local_repos
```

Answer (score 9):

Also, you can try to put port number in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host ComputerA
HostName localhost
Port 1234
```

And then use ComputerA in git clone command:

```
git clone git+ssh://ComputerA/repos local_repos
```

Comment: in my calse <br> yubaofu@~ cat .ssh/config 
Host github.com 
HostName localhost
Port 7070 
yubaofu@~ git clone git+ssh://github.com/fuyou001/yubao-studying.git
Cloning into 'yubao-studying'...<br> can't work

Answer (score 1):

Check out the command files for SSH. You can have a command automatically execute when you log in via SSH. This is specified in the authorized_keys file. So, on Computer A, you will have a command file that automatically SSH-es into Computer B. Then when you connect to Computer A, it will do it automatically to Computer B. To your computer, it is directly connected to Computer B. You can even use a compressed tunnel.

Answer (score -3):

First clone to ComputerA, then clone from ComputerA to ComputerB. You'll have to ssh to ComputerA in order to pull in new stuff, though.